# Set button text when appending to form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have buttons that are created when reading info from a database. When one of the buttons is clicked, a form is created on the fly. The form creates fine, but the problem I am having is setting the text of the button for the form. I have the following to create the form and set the text:

This is the code that sets the button:

```
<button class="replybtn" id="replybtn<?php echo $commid; ?>" value="<?php echo $commid; ?>">Reply</button>
```

And this is the code that creates the form when the button is clicked:

```
$('.replybtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btnnum = $(this).val();
    let replybtn = "replybtn" + btnnum;
    let replyform = "replyform" + btnnum;
    
    var form = $("<form>", {
        action: 'http://intranet/generalinfo/communitybb/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        method: 'POST',
        id: replyform,
        class: 'replyform'
    });

    form.append( $("<textarea>", { 
        name: 'reply', 
        class: 'commentbox',
        rows: '5',
        cols: '150'
    }));

    form.append($("<button>", {
        class: 'replybtn',
        id: replybtn
    }));

    $("#" + replybtn).html = "Reply";
});
```

**EDIT**
Added in the code that sets the variables.

Comment: They are variables that are set when the button is clicked. Sorry, I forgot to add that code. I'll edit it and add it in.

Comment: Please update the demo to show the problem live.

Comment: As cssyphus points out below, `.html` isn't a jQuery  property. It's a method.

Comment: do you want to change the text of `form.append($("<button>", {
        class: 'replybtn',
        id: replybtn
    }))` <- this button on click? Can you Elaborate your question. Still the above code does not generate any form. Cannot reproduce the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button must be appended to the DOM before you can use `$('#id')` to find it. Create a variable with the button instead, change the text and then append the button to the form (and the form to the DOM).

```js
$('.replybtn').click(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    
    var btnnum = $(this).val();
    let replybtn = "replybtn" + btnnum;
    let replyform = "replyform" + btnnum;
    
    var form = $("<form>", {
        action: 'http://intranet/generalinfo/communitybb/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        method: 'POST',
        id: replyform,
        class: 'replyform'
    });
    
    form.append( $("<textarea>", { 
        name: 'reply', 
        class: 'commentbox',
        rows: '5',
        cols: '150'
    }));
    
    let button = $("<button>", {
        class: 'replybtn',
        id: replybtn
    });
    button.text("Reply");

    form.append(button);
    $('#test').append(form);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="replybtn" value="1">Reply</button>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That got it to work. I do have one question though. I found that when I tried to set id to a variable, the form would stop loading for some reason. I can get the form to do what I need it to without setting the id, but would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @DarthMikeyD Hard to say. Be careful not to have duplicate IDs. I know that IDs are "popular" when using jQuery but you don't need IDs for forms and form fields. Use the name attribute instead - they don't need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. I modified the append to the following and that fixed it. Probably not the best way to do it, but it works.

```
form.append($("<button class='cancelbtn' id='cancelbtn" + btnnum + "' value=" + btnnum + ">Cancel</button>"));
```